# Enabling Data Roaming for one application only on my Firefox-OS Phone

Tags: firefox-os

I wanted to use **Usage** default app to determine how much data my own app send when in roaming mode.

I was very surprised to see that my device sent about 500 Mo. Then I realised that other apps on my phone should have used the network also.

So my question is: how can I enable roaming for just my app and prevent network access for everything else (updates, agenda, mail, ...)?

I run Firefox-OS 2.0 on a ZTE-Open device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, this is not possible.**

The [image: Data Usage App Icon] [Data Usage App](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/view-data-usage) performs a test like this using the with the [Network Stats API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Stats_API):

```
var end = new Date();
var start = new Date();

// Returns a mozNetworkStats object
var test = navigator.mozNetworkStats.getSamples('mobile', start, end);
console.log(test);
```

But this test will return a sample of all device connections, not only yours.  The simplest solution is to measure the traffic in your [Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor).

However, if you want to reduce the amount of **mobile traffic** for your application, you can **restrict** all connections to specific connection types (like `wifi`). Just listen to the `typechange` event of the `NetworkInformation.connection` [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NetworkInformation/connection).

In your WebIDE console (Firefox OS `2.0`):

```
navigator.connection
NetworkInformation { type: "wifi", ontypechange: null }
```

or

```
navigator.connection
NetworkInformation { type: "cellular", ontypechange: null }
```

Please notice, that Firefox OS  `<=1.5` will never show you a `cellular` type of connection (it will return `none` if not `wifi`).

Comment: This aswer is interesting, thanks.

But, when you say "this is not possible", are you talking about trafic measurement or about preventing all apps except mine to access network in "cellular" mode?

"cellular" networking is expensive, especially in roaming mode. I don't want to update app through marketplace, neither checking emails when I activate it. This is the main problem. Is ther a solution for this specific point?

Comment: It is not possible, to encapsulate an specific app for traffic measurement and there is no "firewall" to block specific apps for certain network connection types. Sorry.